Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at dashboard/:110:27 django python
i am working on a chart that shows data on the dashbord.
it's taking the data from the db and trying to make a json from that but in the html code it's not working. showing   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input     at JSON.parse ()
this is the view
def dashboard(request):
    mood_data = MentalHealthSurvey.objects.values(
        'mood').annotate(count=Count('mood'))
    stress_data = MentalHealthSurvey.objects.values(
        'stress_level').annotate(count=Count('stress_level'))

    # Serialize data for JavaScript
    mood_data_json = json.dumps(list(mood_data))
    stress_data_json = json.dumps(list(stress_data))

    context = {
        'mood_data_json': mood_data_json,
        'stress_data_json': stress_data_json,
    }

    
    return render(request, 'employees/dashboard.html', {'context': context})

this is the template code.
{% extends 'employees/base_generic.html' %}
{% block title %}
  Employee Dashboard
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Survey Data</h2>
    <canvas id="moodChart"></canvas>
    <canvas id="stressChart"></canvas>
  </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
  <script>
    const moodData = JSON.parse('{{ mood_data_json|safe }}')
    console.log('moodData:', moodData)
    const stressData = JSON.parse('{{ stress_data_json|safe }}')
    
    const moodLabels = (moodData || []).map((item) => item.mood || 'Unknown')
    const moodCounts = (moodData || []).map((item) => item.count || 0)
    
    const stressLabels = (stressData || []).map((item) => item.stress_level || 'Unknown')
    const stressCounts = (stressData || []).map((item) => item.count || 0)
    
    const moodChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('moodChart'), {
      type: 'pie',
      data: {
        labels: moodLabels,
        datasets: [
          {
            data: moodCounts,
            backgroundColor: ['#28a745', '#ffc107', '#dc3545', '#17a2b8', '#6f42c1']
          }
        ]
      }
    })
    
    const stressChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('stressChart'), {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: stressLabels,
        datasets: [
          {
            data: stressCounts,
            backgroundColor: ['#28a745', '#ffc107', '#dc3545']
          }
        ]
      }
    })
  </script>
{% endblock %}



"Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse" - I see multiple uses of JSON.parse in the code shown.  Is one of those throwing the error?  Which one?  When you debug, what is the JSON data being parsed?  Is it what you expect?

yes, const moodData = JSON.parse('{{ mood_data_json|safe }}') here it's giving the error

And... When you debug, what is the JSON data being parsed? Is it what you expect?

Don't use json.dumps and safe to pass data to JavaScript, that is not at all safe and along with that probably prone to failure like it's currently happening for you (My best guess is that your data has a single quote in it somewhere). Use the json_script tag like described here
